# 64 Bit application communicating with 32bit process

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, x86-64

I have 32 bit application  using  32 bit third party library. Now I have to make my application 64 bit , so that it can take advantage of 64 bit address space ( large memory ).
Since I can not load 32bit library into 64bit application process, I am thinking of creating 32bit executable wrapper over third party library and communicate from my 64 bit app using IPC ( named pipe/socket ).
So my question is would their any issue in doing so ?. 
Also if I have to install my application on 64 bit systems, all files related to my application will be copied to "c:\Program Files" directory. Now can I keep my 32 bit third party exe wrapper in the same "c:\Program Files" or I need to copy to "c:\Program Files(x86)" directory ?

Comment: Shared memory (via memory-mapped file) is probably the fastest option for data.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze shared memory between 32-bit and 64-bit seems dubious to me:  "When using shared memory, be aware that a structure in a 32-bit process may have a different size and layout than the same structure in a 64-bit process. This is especially true for structures that contain pointers or handles."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872017(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the way Microsoft recommends for such kind of problems. If you are working with COM, you can make COM exe server. For .NET use WCF. In your case - native C++, no COM - memory-mapped file or pipe is a good choice.

Regarding installation destination folder - you need to test this with the tool used to build installation packages. If the whole installation target is 64 bit, and single executable is 32 bit - the tool may show warning about this file. When the file is executed, it doesn't matter whether it is in Program Files or Program Files (x86), or any other directory.